# Two mail servers in one VPS

Tags: nginx, centos, vps, postfix-mta, dovecot

I have already installed a mail server on my VPS and running without any issues. Lets call it  mail.domain1.com. Now I am planning on hosting another website on the same VPS and a separate mail server for that domain, like mail.domain2.com.

Can anyone assist me through this?

> VPS OS : CentOS
>
> Web Server : Nginx
>
> Mail Server : Postfix & Dovecot

Comment: see here http://www.rosehosting.com/blog/mailserver-with-virtual-users-and-domains-using-postfix-and-dovecot-on-a-centos-6-vps/ .  Or googling with keyword "posfix dovecot virtual user"

Answer (score 0):

You talk about a separate mail server. But why?
You can host multiple domains with one mail server.